# How to load Electron + EEL in python

Tags: python, electron, electron-builder, eel

I am Trying to use Electron browser using EEL. my problem is electron can not load the index.html page.

Python file :

```
import eel
import eel.browsers


eel.init('templates')


eel.browsers.set_path('electron', 'node_modules/electron/dist/electron')


eel.start('index.html', mode='electron' , port=8000  ,host='localhost',disable_cache=True, close_callback='close_callback', )
```

main.js

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('http://localhost:8000/index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
   mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  
  app.on('activate', function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
  })
})

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.
```

Folders Tree :

[image]

As below image, Electron can not locate the index, even I am making electron to load from the localhost server. using
`mainWindow.loadFile('http://localhost:8000/index.html')` and `mainWindow.loadFile('http://localhost:8000/')`

[image]

NOTE : i tried to use localhost:8000 from chrome browser and it is working normally.

Please Help !

Answer (score 1):

I Found the solution for my problem. it seems so simple. but anyway, instead of
`mainWindow.loadFile('http://localhost:8000/') in main.js`.
use   `mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8000/')`